# Move a sphere along the swipe?

Tags: unity, touch, curves

I am trying to get a sphere curl based on the swipe. I know this has been asked many times, but still it's yearning to be answered. 
I have managed to add force on the direction of the swipe and it works near perfect. I also have all the swipe positions stored in a list. Now I would like to know how can the curl be achieved. 
I believe the the curve in the swipe can be calculated by the Vector dot product

[image]

If theta is 0, then there is no need to add the swipe. If it is not, then add the curl. Maybe this condition is redundant if I managed to find how to curl the sphere along the swipe position

The code that adds the force to sphere based on the swipe direction is as below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SwipeControl : MonoBehaviour
{
//First establish some variables
private Vector3 fp; //First finger position
private Vector3 lp; //Last finger position
private Vector3 ip; //some intermediate finger position

private float dragDistance;  //Distance needed for a swipe to register
public float power;
private Vector3 footballPos;
private bool canShoot = true;
private float factor = 40f;

private List<Vector3> touchPositions = new List<Vector3>();


void Start(){

    dragDistance = Screen.height*20/100;
    Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, -20, 0);
    footballPos = transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //Examine the touch inputs
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        /*if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            fp = touch.position;
            lp = touch.position;

        }*/

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            touchPositions.Add(touch.position);
        }

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {

            fp = touchPositions[0];
            lp = touchPositions[touchPositions.Count-1];
            ip = touchPositions[touchPositions.Count/2];





            //First check if it's actually a drag
            if (Mathf.Abs(lp.x - fp.x) > dragDistance || Mathf.Abs(lp.y - fp.y) > dragDistance)
            {   //It's a drag






                //Now check what direction the drag was
                //First check which axis
                if (Mathf.Abs(lp.x - fp.x) > Mathf.Abs(lp.y - fp.y))
                {   //If the horizontal movement is greater than the vertical movement...
                    if ((lp.x>fp.x) && canShoot)  //If the movement was to the right)
                    {   //Right move
                        float x = (lp.x - fp.x) / Screen.height * factor;
                        rigidbody.AddForce((new Vector3(x,10,16))*power);
                        Debug.Log("right "+(lp.x-fp.x));//MOVE RIGHT CODE HERE
                        canShoot = false;
                        //rigidbody.AddForce((new Vector3((lp.x-fp.x)/30,10,16))*power);
                        StartCoroutine(ReturnBall());

                    }
                    else
                    {   //Left move
                        float x = (lp.x - fp.x) / Screen.height * factor;
                        rigidbody.AddForce((new Vector3(x,10,16))*power);
                        Debug.Log("left "+(lp.x-fp.x));//MOVE LEFT CODE HERE
                        canShoot = false;
                        //rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3((lp.x-fp.x)/30,10,16)*power);
                        StartCoroutine(ReturnBall());
                    }
                }
                else
                {   //the vertical movement is greater than the horizontal movement
                    if (lp.y>fp.y)  //If the movement was up
                    {   //Up move
                        float y = (lp.y-fp.y)/Screen.height*factor;
                        float x = (lp.x - fp.x) / Screen.height * factor;
                        rigidbody.AddForce((new Vector3(x,y,16))*power);
                        Debug.Log("up "+(lp.x-fp.x));//MOVE UP CODE HERE
                        canShoot = false;
                        //rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3((lp.x-fp.x)/30,10,16)*power);
                        StartCoroutine(ReturnBall());
                    }
                    else
                    {   //Down move
                        Debug.Log("down "+lp+" "+fp);//MOVE DOWN CODE HERE
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {   //It's a tap
                Debug.Log("none");//TAP CODE HERE
            }

        }
    }

}


IEnumerator ReturnBall() {

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);
    rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    transform.position = footballPos;
    canShoot =true;
    isKicked  = false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I have written a utility class in a game before for handling [Bezier Curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). You may try to use the points along the swiping path as control points. Though I did not make use of any physics stuff for calculations, the outcome should satisfy your need.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class BezierCurve {
    public static Vector3 Lerp(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, Vector3[] controlPoints, float time) {
        Vector3[] points = new Vector3[controlPoints.Length + 2];
        points[0] = start;
        points[points.Length - 1] = end;
        Array.Copy(controlPoints, 0, points, 1, controlPoints.Length);
        return Lerp(points, time);
    }

    public static Vector3 Lerp(Vector3[] points, float time) {
        Vector3 ret = Vector3.zero;

        if (points != null && points.Length > 0) {
            int n = points.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                Vector3 cp = points[i];
                cp *= BinomialCoefficient(n - 1, i);
                cp *= Mathf.Pow(1 - time, n - i - 1);
                cp *= Mathf.Pow(time, i);
                ret += cp;
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    static int BinomialCoefficient(int n, int k) {
        int nCk = 1;

        if (k >= 1 && k <= n - 1) {
            int numerator = 1;
            int denominator = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                numerator *= (n - i);
                denominator *= (k - i);
            }

            nCk = (int)(numerator / denominator);
        }

        return nCk;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to the concept of the Bezier curves and forgive me if I say something wrong, but, I believe apart from the start and end points all the other control points does no lie on the swipe/curve. How do I go about this, if whatever I have understood is right?

Comment: @gameOne So you want to join points up and form a smooth curve, right?

Comment: yes that's right!

Comment: After doing a bit searching, I believe [this site](http://www.particleincell.com/blog/2012/bezier-splines/) can help you.

Comment: will check it out and get back

Comment: While the control points of a bezier curve are not exactly on the curve they are still pretty close. I doubt that the user will notice the discrepancy. If you really need the points to be exactly on the curve you could check out hermite-interpolation